# android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE granted but access denied

Tags: android, file, android-permissions

The following code output is "Write granted" but after that the error it '/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)'

What's wrong?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class FileStorageTest {

    private static final String TAG = FileStorageTest.class.getSimpleName();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Write granted");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Write refused");
        }

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"test.txt");
        new FileOutputStream(file).close();
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you also need to use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to read data from the device.`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Sir don't we need to define for both the permission at `Runtime` ?

Comment: @jaydroider you can but the docs say *If an app requests a dangerous permission listed in its manifest, and the app already has another dangerous permission in the same permission group, the system immediately grants the permission without any interaction with the user.*

Comment: is your sdk version >=23?

Comment: @jaydroider yes that's it I needed to also grant READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. You can write the solution so I can accept it.

Comment: @TimCastelijns No in my case WRITE was not enough, it started to work when I added READ

Comment: Yes my mistake. Granting 1 does not grant the other, but what it does do is it automatically grants the other the moment you request it

Comment: @RenaudBlue I have added as answer below.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Sir this information is helped for more understanding :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to also add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to read data from the device.
>
> Add this permission also at `RunTime`.

```
    if (context.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Read granted");
    } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Read refused");
    }
```

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE also exists, however, the file still cannot be read. By running in debug mode, I checked if file exists (TRUE), checked if file can be read (FALSE), checked if can be written (FALSE), checked if write and read for external storage granted (TRUE for both). Any other updated suggestion?

Comment: @ranka47 Please post your exact issue in new question so that can get idea what exactly issues you are facing and what you have tried please.

Comment: I had raised and seemed to be the issue with the change of how Android 10 treats its external storage. It got resolved by this question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379543/cant-create-directory-in-android-10. I resolved it by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```