# Can't create directory in Android 10

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to create directory in android 10. It's working on devices till android Oreo.

I tried two ways for creating folders.

**Using** `File.mkdir()`:

```
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pastebin");
                    if (!f.isFile()) {
                        if (!(f.isDirectory())) {
                               success =  f.mkdir();
                        }
```

Here, the variable `success`  is always **false** which means the directory isn't created.

**Using** `Files.createDirectory()`:

```
   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pastebin");
                    if (!f.isFile()) {
                        if (!(f.isDirectory())) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                try {
                                    Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.unable_to_download, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                f.mkdir();
                            }
                        }
```

which causes this exception:

```
pzy64.pastebinpro W/System.err: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Pastebin
pzy64.pastebinpro W/System.err:     at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:391)
pzy64.pastebinpro W/System.err:     at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
```

I've implemented the run-time permissions and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

are all set.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As was first disclosed back in March 2019, you no longer have access by default to arbitrary locations on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 10+. This includes `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and other methods on `Environment` (e.g., `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

For Android 10 and 11, you can add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest. This opts you into the legacy storage model, and your existing external storage code will work.

Otherwise, your choices are:

- Use methods on `Context`, such as `getExternalFilesDir()`, to get at directories on external storage into which your app can write. You do not need any permissions to use those directories on Android 4.4+. However, the data that you store there gets removed when your app is uninstalled.
- Use the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.
- If your content is media, you can use `MediaStore` to place the media in standard media locations.

Comment: are you saying that there is no way to create my own directory on Android Q?

Comment: @Xihuny: You are welcome to create subdirectories of `getExternalFilesDir()` and similar locations supplied by `Context`. You cannot create subdirectories off of the roots of external or removable storage directly, using filesystem APIs.

Comment: I don't want to do that because the files will be removed when user uninstall the app.

Comment: @Xihuny: Then use the Storage Access Framework and allow the user to choose where on the user's device you put the user's content.

Comment: I tried, but I was not able to create my own directory. Is there a way to create my own custom named directory using SAF?

Comment: @Xihuny: You can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose a document tree. From there, use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` for that document tree. You can then create children (documents and trees) in that tree, with whatever names you want. Whether it is a "directory" depends on what the user chooses as the base document tree -- there is no requirement that they choose something on the filesystem.

Comment: So, the user has to select a directory and ```Allow Access``` to that directory before the app can create any other directory inside?

Comment: @Xihuny: Correct.

Comment: Is there any way to open ```Intent``` to specific directory? For example, I want to open the ```Intent``` in Pictures folder.

Comment: @Xihuny: "Is there any way to open Intent to specific directory?" -- if you mean `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, you can use `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`, but that has to be a `Uri` that you previously received from SAF.

Comment: I updated my device to Android 10 and noticed this issue now. Till Pie, it is able to create a folder in root sdcard(/sdcard/0/ or Internal Shred Storage) where the user download stuffs thru my app which need not to be deleted when the  app is uninstalled. I'll try to fix this this, if i am able to do this, i'll write an answer ;)

Comment: @chankruze are you able to solve this issue if yes then please do share. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xihuny        In Android 11 we cannot get access to Downloads folder using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and I want to put all my files in a directory like Downloads/MyDirectory. What should I do? Is letting my user create MyDirectory himself the only option?

Comment: Great Explanation! Worked for me.. just by adding a line inside <application> tag of Android manifest file.. android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". I am creating folder with code lines..

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "Test Folder";
File file = new File(path);
if (!file.exists())
 file.mkdirs();

Answer (score 20):

For Android 10, you can add

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

to your  element in the manifest. This opts you into the legacy storage model, and your existing external storage code will work. This fix will not work on Android R and higher though, so this is only a short-term fix.

Comment: unless your targetSDK >= 30 it will still work in Android 11 & beyond.

Comment: What's the long term fix for Android 11?

Answer (score 12):

There are more restrictions in Android `API 30`

you can only write in your `app-specific files`

```
 File dir_ = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "YOUR_DIR");
 dir_.mkdirs();
```

or in the external storage of your app `Android/data`

```
File dir_ = new File(myContext.getExternalFilesDir("FolderName"),"YOUR_DIR");
```

UPDATE

this answer provided another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744517/8195076

UPDATE

another way is to grant this permission in `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66968986/8195076

Comment: Woow this has worked for me, remember to set android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your manifest

Answer (score 6):

This works for me and I think it's functional on Android 10>

```java
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Folder Example");
String path = String.valueOf(resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues));
File folder = new File(path);
boolean isCreada = folder.exists();
if(!isCreada) {
    folder.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: You are querying a `File`, so you will have to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` when targeting Android 10>. In that case, you might as well keep using `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is Deprecated in API level 29

Comment: Yes, and? As the documentation states `When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible`, so if you have `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your manifest, you can still use it.

Comment: "Yes, and?" and, as the documentation states `Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`
I am new to this but then my question would be, is my proposal wrong or why the negative vote? I don't know very well how this works, is it better then to continue with `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`?

Comment: Firstly, it wasn't me who downvoted. To answer your question, you are querying a file, which is not allowed on Android 10>, unless you request legacy storage. To do it correctly, you should get the `Uri`, like this `Uri mUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);` then use that `Uri` directly instead of passing it to a `File` object.

Comment: An apology, this is just how I create the Uri `resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);` As I said I am new programming for android but it seems to me that if it is necessary to passing to File to create the folder, sorry bad english

Comment: You do not have to create a folder. When you write to the `Uri` the folder gets created automatically.

Comment: @HB. But what if we only want to create the folder?

Answer (score 5):

You can use public directory to save files in Android 11 like this:

```
dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath()
    + "/foldername");

if (!dir.exists()) {
     dir.mkdir();
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This is working in Android 12 but not in Android 9 and 10 devices. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) is not available in those so replaced that with Context.getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) but no folder was created. Documents folder is not seen in Android 9 and 10

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated on new versions, use `MediaStore` queries and `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` (or the directory you require) instead

Answer (score 4):

Since Q beta 4 it's possible to opt-out of that feature by:

targeting api 28 (or lower)
using requestLegacyExternalStorage manifest attribute:

```
<manifest ... >
  <!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android Q. -->
  <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

only use

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in manifests

Comment: this is only for android version < android 11. Not applicable for android version greater then 10.

Comment: @user6159419 Yes and on Android 11>, `File` path access is once again allowed. So, `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` is to ensure it works on Android 10.