# Android 10 How to create file/folder in file manger that is accesible with all app

Tags: android, file-manager, android-10.0

I am using the below code to create a directory/ file in storage.

```
   File file  = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "/MyDirectory");
```

After updating target SDK version 29 in android 10 its not woking.

can anyone suggest how to create a folder outside the application scope?

Answer (score -3):

**For Android version 10:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379655/3811983

---

**For Android versions below Android 10:**
(including this here as no one develops only for Android 10. This will make it a complete answer for anyone looking for including this functionality in their apps)

Here are the steps that I followed, and are working for me:

- Include the following permission in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

- Since WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is dangerous permission, at app runtime, check if the app has this permission, if not, request the user to grant it.

[Doc1](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) 
[Doc2](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions)
[AirPermissions](https://github.com/mumayank/AirPermissionsLibraryProject) (A lightweight library to simplify Android Runtime Permissions)

- Check if external storage is present and the app can read and write to it

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
     // further code here
}
```

- If everything is right, you can proceed to create your public directory:

```
val rootFile = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
val appRootFolder = File(rootFile.absolutePath + "/MyDirectory")
if (appRootFolder.exists() && appRootFolder.isDirectory) {
     // proceed
} else {
     val wasAppRootFolderCreated = appRootFolder.mkdirs()
     if (wasAppRootFolderCreated) {
          // proceed
     } else {
          // error: could not create the folder
     }
}
```

Comment: This does not work on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps). The question specifically was about Android 10.