# Android Q, how to save audio recording with MediaStore with the correct file name?

Tags: android, file, audio-recording, mediastore, scoped-storage

I want to store my mp3 files recorded with my app to the Music folder with MediaStore for the new "Scoped Storage" of Android 10.
This method works good, but the files are named with timestamp (e.g. 1576253519449), without `.mp3` extension.
If I add the extension manually with file manager, the file is recorded correctly.
How i can use `fileName + ".mp3"` to name the files?

```
String fileName; //Obtained by intent
MediaRecorder audioRecorder;
Uri audiouri;
ParcelFileDescriptor file;

private void startRecording() throws IOException {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/Recordings/");

    audiouri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    file = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(audiouri, "w");

    if (file != null) {
        audioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        audioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        audioRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getFileDescriptor());
        audioRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        audioRecorder.prepare();
        audioRecorder.start();
    }
}
```

[image]

And another question: `MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH` is only for Android 10.
How to maintain retrocompatibility with older releases?

**EDIT:**
For retrocompatibility, you can just remove `values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/Recordings/");`: the files will be saved directly in Music directory.
Or use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)` to add the subdirectory only on Android 10.

Comment: Use DISPLAY_NAME.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm.

Comment: @blackapps I'm wondering how to do the same for devices prior to Android Q using the media store API?

Comment: Then use .DATA column.

Comment: @FirestormXYZ, how can I create new directory in android Q just like whatsapp is doing like i want path should be **.../0/AudioRecording**. Here **AudioRecording** is a folder where i want to store my recording files.

Comment: @OMIHARISHCHANDRAMEHTA For Android 10 and 11, you can add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to your <application> element in the manifest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379655/3605220
But start to save your recordings inside applications dedicated folder, because in future releases of android you won't be able to create folders anymore, even with this legacy method.
Neither whatsapp won't be able to do it anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @blackapps suggested, can be used the `DISPLAY_NAME` property.