# [Android]Java.io.IOException: Permission denied when WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is set

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage

I tried to store file in android, but I couldn't do it.
 First, I added two permissions in Androidmenifest.xml using  tags like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And, added logic that check two permissions in MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       btn = findViewById(R.id.button)

       btn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{

       override fun onClick(v: View?) {
           checkPermission()
       }
     })

    }
    private fun checkPermission() {
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Read/Write external storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                            101)
                } else { 
                    writeFile()
                }
            }
        }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
            when (requestCode) {
                101 -> if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    writeFile()
                } else {
                    Log.d("MainActivty", "Permission always deny")
                }
            }
        }

    private fun writeFile() {
            val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator.toString() + "temp.txt")
            try {
                Log.d("MainActivty", "create new File : " + file.createNewFile())
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Finally, I started it by embedded Amulator. But, There are Permission denied.

Error log is here :

```
2020-03-12 15:46:22.317 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    2020-03-12 15:46:22.318 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
    2020-03-12 15:46:22.318 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
    2020-03-12 15:46:22.318 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1008)
    2020-03-12 15:46:22.318 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err:     at com.techtown.permissiontest.MainActivity.writeFile(MainActivity.kt:77)
    2020-03-12 15:46:22.319 4148-4148/com.techtown.permissiontest W/System.err:     at com.techtown.permissiontest.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Android Q?......

Comment: @blackapps yes. right.

Comment: That directory is not usable under Android Q anymore. This has been reported here the last months twice or three times a day.

Comment: @blackapps Oh, That's new to me. If you're okay, can I get a document or link related to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379543, https://stackoverflow.com/q/57116335

Comment: @MikeM. Oh, I solve it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

add the following
permission`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);`