# how to open file with another app in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

hi i want open excel files from my app in another office app i used this codes

```
val file = File(path)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            activity!!.applicationContext,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.toString() + ".provider",
            file
        )
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        //file is word
        if (file.extension.contains("doc")){
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/word")

        }else{
            // file is excel
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/excel")
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
            activity.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            snack(view,"برنامه ای برای نمایش فایل ورد/اکسل روی گوشی پیدا نشد، لطفا برنامه آفیس را روی گوشی خود نصب کنید")
        }
```

but this code not work properly and it doesn't work on some phones and Android 10 So how do I make it work on all phones?

Comment: Does this help? https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-files-in-code-after-the-android-10-released-2bea0e16d35

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create directory in Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379543/cant-create-directory-in-android-10)

Comment: "this code not work properly and it doesn't work on some phones and Android 10" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, describe what the exact observed behavior is and what the expected/intended behavior should be. For UI issues, a screenshot or video is usually helpful. Include the exact text of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way myself. I post it here, maybe it helped someone

```
val file = File(path)

        val myMime: MimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        val mimeType: String =
            myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension).toString()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            newIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity!!.applicationContext, activity.applicationContext.packageName.toString() +
                ".provider", file), mimeType)
        }else{
            newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType)
        }
        newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        try {
            activity!!.startActivity(newIntent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            snack(view,"برنامه ای برای نمایش فایل ورد/اکسل روی گوشی پیدا نشد، لطفا برنامه آفیس را روی گوشی خود نصب کنید")
        }
```

also you need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/13466723)