# Why I can't works whit files in android 10?

Tags: android-file

It's about a week that I upgrade my android version to 10 before that i can work whit files in my app but now I can't do anything such as:

**Can't Create Folder**

```
File internal = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()));
internal.mkdirs();
```

**Can't Delete folder**

```
File internal = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()));
    internal.delete();
```

**Can't Get List of Folders In side It**

```
File internal = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()));
    String[] internalFiles = internal.list();
```

please some one help me if you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804657/588532

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379543 answer to your question?

Comment: somewhat but I still can't make file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was first disclosed back in March 2019, you no longer have access by default to arbitrary locations on external storage or removable storage on Android 10+. add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your manifest. Then will work.