# Accessing files created by Android app through the USB cable from PC

Tags: android, external

I was previously using getExternalStorageDirectory() which allowed my Android app to read and write files in the sdcard/music directory (/storage/emulated/0/Music). This way I was able to manually exchange these files with my Windows PC through the USB port with Windows Explorer.

Could someone show me or give me a hint on how I can transfer these files between my app and Windows Explorer now that getExternalStorageDirectory() is not working for API29.

This is the lines of code that I need to replace:

public class BrowseMusic extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_decoder);
    this.setTitle("Browse");


    FilenameFilter filter = new GenericExtFilter(".evs",".EVS",".pcap",".PCAP");
    String[] listOfFiles = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).list(filter);
    {
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            ListView codecFileList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listD);
            codecFileList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfFiles));
            codecFileList.setOnItemClickListener(new returnClickedItem());
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code I used to be able to list the directory /storage/emulated/0/Music and I was able to later access the files that my app created through the usb cable.

But if I use getExternalFilesDir() instead

```
    String[] listOfFiles = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).list(filter);
```

I can list the directory /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.evsdemo/files/Music. This works fine for my app but I am not able to access that directory through the usb cable. In fact when I use Android Studio's Device File Explorer I can see the directory when working with an AVD but not with a physical Android Phone connected to usb. Any ideas are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Request legacy external storage in manifest file and you can continue as you used to do.

Comment: Related: [Can't create directory in Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58379543/295004)