# I am developing a kivymd app but app is crashing after taking permissions

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

#### I am developing an android app in kivymd . but when I am testing it .it's crashing in some device and running fine in other device .This is my permission code for read/write

```
        if platform == 'android':
            from android.permissions import Permission , request_permissions
            def callback(permissions,results):
                if all([res for res in results]):
                    print("Got all Permissions")
                else:
                    print("did not get all permissions!")
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE] , callback)
```

#### Error's

```
2021-04-29 20:22:51.731 6604-6604/? W/SDLThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:23390110): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/org.kpkundali.kpkundali.astrologyapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules/mmap.cpython-37m.so" dev="dm-1" ino=140498 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c204,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c204,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file
2021-04-29 20:22:51.951 6604-6636/? I/python:  Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-04-29 20:22:51.951 6604-6636/? I/python:    File "/home/manish/kpkundali/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1593, in <module>
2021-04-29 20:22:51.952 6604-6636/? I/python:    File "/home/manish/kpkundali/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/kpkundali.astrologyapp/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
2021-04-29 20:22:51.952 6604-6636/? I/python:    File "/home/manish/kpkundali/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1571, in build
2021-04-29 20:22:51.953 6604-6636/? I/python:    File "/home/manish/kpkundali/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 895, in __init__
2021-04-29 20:22:51.953 6604-6636/? I/python:  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/kundali'
2021-04-29 20:22:51.953 6604-6636/? I/python: Python for android ended.
```

Comment: It'd be useful to know which line this refers to `File "/home/manish/kpkundali/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 895, in __init__`

Comment: ```if platform == 'android':
            if not path.exists(self.app_folder + "/kundali"):
                mkdir(self.app_folder + "/kundali")```

Comment: this is the code at line 895

Comment: and app_folder variable is ```from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
        app_folder = primary_external_storage_path()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! It was due to Android version update in 2019 . It is working on below Android 10 devices but not working on Android 10 or higher because they restricted external file storage access directly. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379655/8737614) answer.
Solution for this problem is we can use Internal app storage for creating folder and files but when we uninstall our app we will lose all files that we stored.