# AccessDeniedException WatchService android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, watchservice, fileobserver

i'm trying to build an app that notices when a file is created.
I've used WatchService but when i attempt to "register" there is the following error:

```
W/System.err: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Wow
W/System.err:     at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.implRegister(LinuxWatchService.java:275)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
        at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:352)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I've also add all permissions in my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyWatchservice"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MainClass"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />

            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my code in MainClass.java

```
                WatchService service = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
                Path path = Paths.get(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Wow");
                Log.e("test",path.toString());
    
                File dir5 = new File(String.valueOf(path));
                if(dir5.exists())
                    Log.e("test1","ye");
                else
                    Log.e("test1","nope");
    
    
                WatchKey key;
                path.register(service, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
                ...
```

Comment: Do you have "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"" in your manifest?

Comment: (@DavidLee: does the `application`-element from the second "code" block do? I see no `/>` (to end an empty element), no closing tag.)

Comment: From *Android storage use cases and best practices*: [Caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on those devices.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases): what API level are you targeting?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [opting into the legacy storage model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379655)?

Comment: yes i have android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in my manifest, i've edit the question with full manifest

Comment: @greyberad That's all you need in the `application` tag.

Comment: (@DavidLee: I asked *element*, you answered *tag*. SempriGno commented `[I've edited] the question with full manifest` - I'm none the wiser. *I* have any neither manifest nor android?!)

Comment: now it's updated, i can't put the entire manifests, too code....

Comment: @greybeard Target Api: 26

Comment: @DavidLee now it's updated