# Trigger when a new file is created android

Tags: java, android, watchservice, fileobserver

I'm trying to create an app that notices when a new file is created in a certain directory of Internal Storage...
I've tried with WatchService with no success :
[AccessDeniedException WatchService android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203615/accessdeniedexception-watchservice-android-studio)
I've also tried with FileObserver but the method onEvent is never called.
What should i use?
Target API: 26 and higher