# Cannot add file to specific folder location for Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, android-10.0

I am trying to create a PDF file and add it to the internal storage of the android phone. I want to create a directory for my app outside the app data folder so the phone user could access it from its Files system app.

The code I am using to create the folder is the following :

```
 File myDir = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "MyApp");
        if(!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = new File(myDir, customer+"_"+date+".pdf");
```

How can I fix this problem please?

Okay this code leads me to save the file in this location
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapplication/files/Download/MyApp"

I want to move it to /storage/emulated/0/MyApp

I used to write this code, but now that 'getExternalStorageDirectory' is deprecated

```
File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(externalStorageDirectory, "MyApp"); 
if (!dir.exists()) { 
    dir.mkdir(); 
}
```

Comment: Besides that you should have `if (!myDir.mkdir()) return;` your code is ok. So what is the problem,?

Comment: Why are you talking both about internal and external storage? Confusing! And why did you mention downloading? Is that relevant? And a FileNotFoundException which cannot be produced by the code you posted. Confusing!

Comment: The problem is that I want to create the folder "MyApp" in internal storage not in Android/data/app folder
I want to access "/storage/emulated/0" and then create the directory to add the folder
When I replace the directory with /storage/emulated/0, I get FilenotFoundException (Android 10)

Comment: Which code will give that exception? Not the code you posted.

Comment: @blackapps I want to create a directory first in internal storage and then add a file to it. 
I want the phone user to be able to access this file

Comment: "/storage/emulated/0" this location is giving me the File not found

Comment: I read about the new restrictions in android 10 concerning root folder and storage folder

Comment: `I want to create the folder "MyApp" in internal storage not in Android/data/app folder ` Sorry, besides that you fail to mention full path, that IS internal storage. AND external. Full path: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app folder/files/MyApp`.

Comment: `"/storage/emulated/0" this location is giving me the File not found ` That is just a string. Which code would produce the exception? You did not tell.

Comment: And please adapt the mkdirs calls first. Dont talk about not beeing able to create a file where you cannot even create the folder where you wanna put a file in. Now you try to create a file in a folder that does not exist.

Comment: Now for the third time. Adapt the code where you call mkdir(). And tell what your problem is then. It does not matter that that function is deprecated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379543/cant-create-directory-in-android-10 for a more modern solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try the following codes, but I used them a while ago in an app:

```
String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/My Folder").getPath();
createNewFolder ( path );
```

The createNewFolder method creates a folder and displays a toast if created, and displays another toast if the folder name already exists:

```
private void createNewFolder(String path)
    {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
            Toast.makeText( context , "Folder created" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText( context , "Folder already exists" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code also suffers from blind mkdir() use.